# Clicking on an input with capybara

Tags: html, css, ruby, capybara

I was wondering how to click on a input in capybara.

So far I've tried

```
click_on('#js-emu-submit.button.pl3.pr3.mb0.mr1')
click('js-emu-submit')
find('input', exact_text: 'Get an Estimate', match: :first).click
```

None of them have worked

This is the HTML from the webpage.

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Get an Estimate" id="js-emu-submit" class="button pl3 pr3 mb0 mr1" data-disable-with="Get an Estimate">
```

I am just wondering how to click on the item.

Comment: use addeventlisener

Comment: Describe “None of them have worked”. Do you get errors, or just the behavior you expect the click to trigger doesn’t occur?

Comment: What driver are you using for Capybara?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for `click_on` - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_link_or_button-instance_method - you can see that it's a combination of `click_button` and `click_link` and says to check each of those for the type of locator it accepts.  Looking at `click_button`, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method, you can see that it will find `any <input> element of type submit, reset, image, button` (which your HTML element is) and that the locator can be any of `id, Capybara.test_id attribute, value, or title`. A CSS selector is not one of those things so that explains why your `click_on` attempt fails. Assuming your <input> element is visible on the page then any of the following should click it

```
click_on 'js-emu-submit' # match on id
click_button 'js-emu-submit' # id
click_button 'Get an Estimate' # match on value - should work with `click_on` too
```

The other option is to just use `click` on an element located another way. `click` does not take a locator - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method - so that explains why your second attempt doesn't work, and an input element doesn't have child text inside the element so that explains why your third attempt doesn't work. Things that should work using `click` would be

```
find('#js-emu-submit').click # find element by CSS id selector and click it
find(:button, 'js-emu-submit').click # find by id using the :button selector
find('input[value="Get an Estimate"]').click # find by CSS attribute selector
...
```